# как обновить ObjectStateManager?

Tags: css3

как обновить ObjectStateManager?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно работает

```
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _
Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries())
```

А вообще пропишите вгугле objectstatemanager refresh